# Show/Hide WYSIWYG (summernote) toolbar on focus/non-focus

Tags: wysiwyg, summernote

I'm using the summernote WYSIWYG editor and on my page there could be several fields that could be edited with WYSIWYG formatting although I'd like to hide the toolbar on all textfields and only show the toolbar when the user have pressed within the textfield for one of the WYSIWYG fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, using airmode was good enough!

```
airMode: true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass toolbar as false

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
      toolbar: false,
      .....
});
```